# Oracle OJDBC Class not found exception using PySpark with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, ojdbc

I am trying to read data from Oracle DB by using JDBC connection and I am getting following error:

"name": "Py4JJavaError",
"message": "An error occurred while calling o36.load.\n: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \nFailed to find data source: ojdbc. Please find packages at\nhttps://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html\n       \r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:207)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:171)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\r\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\r\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\r\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\r\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\r\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\r\n\tat py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)\r\n\tat py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ojdbc.DefaultSource\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)\r\n\tat scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)\r\n\tat scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)\r\n\t... 15 more\r\n"

**My Oracle version is 11g and I am using ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar**

## Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'path\\to\\ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar') \
    .config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', 'path\\to\\ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar') \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("app") \
    .getOrCreate() 

df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
        .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xxx.xx:1521:schemaname")\
        .option("dbtable", "table")\
        .option("user", "user")\
        .option("password","password")\
        .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
        .load()
```

Can someone guide me why we are getting classMotFound Exception and what I am missing.

Thank you in advance and looking for some suggestions.

Comment: Have you put the jars in executor drivers manually to the path specified ?

Comment: I am running this code in vs code notebook and I setup this manually in the code

Comment: I think these options require the jar to be already present in the executor and driver, i.e. they won't ship the jar. Can you add more environment details and how are you launching the notebook?

Comment: Goto spark installed folder and place oracle jar inside jars folder.

Comment: it got resolved after placing the jar in SPARK_HOME directory. Thank you Ronak and Mohana for your response.